# Unique value number between <>

Tags: unique, splunk, splunk-query

How can I get unique value number for below.

`SeqNum<number>, by host name`.

Appreciate your help in advance

Thank you

I tried

```
| Search SeqNum<*>
| Stats count by host
```

Getting table and  total value by host but not getting unique number value

Comment: What does the data look like?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are looking for a count of unique "SeqNum" numbers you can do something like following:

```
| search SeqNum<*>
| rex "SeqNum\<(?<number>\d+)\>"
| stats count as total, dc(number) as unique_numbers by host
```

Answer (score 0):

| stats count by host
| streamstats count as seqnum

This will give a unique sequence number for each host